# Highcharts show x-axis labels as weekly intervals

Tags: angular, highcharts

I'm having data of one month in weekly intervals displayed in column-chart.
Currently each week is displayed as one column. This is fine, but the labels are for each column like:

- 'Sunday, June 23, 2019'
- 'Sunday, June 30, 2019'
- etc...

I would like to show one column like '*Week June 23 - June 30*' or something similar.

I tried messing around with **x-axis label formatting** and **tickinterval**, but I can't get the data of next data point in there.

My question is: is this even possible with highcharts and if yes, then can somebody give me some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `formatter` function and add one week in milliseconds to the current label value:

```
xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime',
    labels: {
        formatter: function() {
            return 'Week ' + Highcharts.dateFormat(
                '%B %d',
                this.value
            ) + ' - ' + Highcharts.dateFormat(
                '%B %d',
                this.value + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
            )
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4bk1s3ho/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.labels.formatter

Comment: Solved the issue for me. Thanks!